# How to count an object after passing through the line?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, opencv3.0, yolo

I have detected the object in the video frames and labelled it and also count the total objects in the frame but my question is how can i count the object after passing the line as shown in image. and also with the object category.

Here is my code

In the image i have count the total object in the frame but i want to **count them when they cross the line**.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3.weights','yolov3.cfg')
classes = []
with open('coco.names','r') as f:
    classes = f.read().splitlines()
# printing the data which is loaded from the names file
#print(classes)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while True:
    _,img = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = img.shape
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255,  (416 , 416), (0,0,0) ,swapRB=True,crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layer_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutput = net.forward(output_layer_names)
    boxes = []
    person =0
    truck =0
    car = 0
    confidences = []
    class_ids =[]
    for output in layerOutput:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.5:
                center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                center_y = int(detection[1]*height)
                w = int(detection[2]*width)
                h = int(detection[3]*height)


                x = int(center_x - w/2)
                y = int(center_y - h/2)

                boxes.append([x,y,w,h])
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)
    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes,confidences,0.5,0.4)
    font = cv2.QT_FONT_NORMAL
    colors = np.random.uniform(0,255,size=(len(boxes),3))
    for i in indexes.flatten():
        labelsss = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
        if(labelsss == 'person'):
            person+=1
        if(labelsss == 'car'):
            car+=1
        if(labelsss == 'truck'):
            truck+=1

    for i in indexes.flatten():
        x,y,w,h = boxes[i]
        label =str(classes[class_ids[i]])
        confidence = str(round(confidences[i],1))
        color = colors[i]
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w , y+h), color, 2)
        cv2.line(img,(1000,250),(5,250),(0,0,0),2)
              
        cv2.putText(img, label + " ", (x, y+20), font, 0.5, (255,255,255),2)
        cv2.putText(img, 'Car'+ ":" + str(car), (20, 20), font, 0.8, (0,0,0),2)
        cv2.putText(img, 'Person'+ ":" + str(person), (20, 50), font, 0.8, (0,0,0),2)
        cv2.putText(img, 'Truck'+ ":" + str(truck), (20, 80), font, 0.8, (0,0,0),2)
        cv2.imshow('Image',img)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == 10:
            break
        
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did a project just like this during my internship. You can check out the code here: https://github.com/sarimmehdi/nanonets_object_tracking/blob/master/test_on_video.py

In a nutshell: You should instead draw a rectangle (narrow) and count a tracked ID when it passes through the rectangle. If the rectangle is just narrow enough, you can also avoid the problem of re-identification.

Comment: Can you explain the technique how did you track the object !!!! i want to get the logic....

Comment: I saw the tracklets in your picture. So, I am assuming you already know how to track the object (I was using Deep SORT in my approach). Anyways, replace your line in the figure with a rectangle. Let (x1,y1) be coordinates of top-left and (x2,y2) be coordinates of bottom-right. Let (x,y) be centroid of your tracklet. If x1 <= x <= x2 and y1 <= y <= y2, then count that ID and add a one to your object count. Do this for every other object.